# How to specify a condition in an Entity Framework join?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Blogs table related to BlogComments table with a FK.

I need to get, through Linq, all the BlogComments items that match a certain flag

If i do:

```
db.Blogs.Where(b => b.BlogComments.Where(bc=>bc.Where(bc.Flag1==true));
```

I get "Cannot implicity convert type IEnumerable to bool"

Which is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this expression:

```
b.BlogComments.Where(...)
```

returns an IEnumerable (of BlogComments), but you are then passing it into this method:

```
db.Blogs.Where(...)
```

which expects a function that returns a bool, not an IEnumerable.

You probably need something like this:

```
var blogId = 5;
db.BlogComments.Where(bc => bc.BlogId == blogId && bc.Flag1 == true)
```

If you need to select comments from multiple blogs, then you could try using Contains:

```
var blogIds = new [] {1,2,3,4,5};
db.BlogComments.Where(bc => blogIds.Contains(bc.BlogId) && bc.Flag1 == true)
```

If you want to place criteria on the set of blogs, as well as the comments, then you could do this in one query using a join:

```
var query = from b in db.Blogs
            join c in db.BlogComments on c.Blog equals b
            where b.SomeField == "some value"
            && c.Flag1 == true
            select c;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write it in LINQ form.

```
var blogs = from b in db.Blogs
            join c in db.BlogComments
            on b.BlogId equals c.BlogId
            where c.Flag1
            select b;
```

If you have a composite key you can write

```
on new { A = b.BlogKey1, B = b.BlogKey2 }
  equals new { A = c.CommentKey1, B = c.CommentKey2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would just have another DbSet in your DbContext.

```
DbSet<BlogComment> BlogComments
```

and just search through there without going through Blogs.

```
db.BlogComments.Where(bc => bc.Flag1 == true);
```

If anyone knows if there's anything wrong in doing so, then I'm all ears :)

Comment: the problem is that i have to extract all the comments related to a certaint set of blog items, so i need to work starting from Blog items and gettings BlogComments related to them.